# UPDATE + WITH (ROWLOCK) + CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I can't find any documentation about syntax for T-SQL statement:
I need to make an `WITH (ROWLOCK)` UPDATE on a CTE result.

Something like: (so updated will be top1000 table1.col2. Statement `WITH (ROWLOCK)` during an UPDATE on rows of table1 is crucial)

```
    ;WITH CTE AS 
    ( 
        SELECT TOP(1000) table1.col2
        FROM  table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id    
    ) 
    UPDATE CTE WITH (ROWLOCK)
    SET col2 = 1
```

The above statement is probably syntactically correct, however if someone will find such example, please give me a link.

BUT: my full SQL looks like below. During execute I get error:

> Conflicting locking hints are specified for table "table1". This may be caused by a conflicting hint specified for a view.

Why can't I use `WITH (NOLOCK)` for selecting and `WITH (ROWLOCK)` on updating?

```
;WITH CTE AS 
( 
    SELECT TOP(5) table1.col2
    FROM table1 WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN table2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON table1.id = table2.id 
    WHERE table1.col3 = 2
    ORDER BY table1.id    
) 
UPDATE CTE WITH (ROWLOCK)
SET col2 = 1
```

Comment: Syntactically that is a valid statement, but two challenges with it are:  you've not got an order by statement so don't know which rows you are actually going to update and; the rowlock is just a hint to the optimizer so may be used or may not be used.  Why do you need a rowlock anyway?

Comment: @PaulMcLoughlin Thanks for answer. I wasn't able to google any sample code with such 'sql combination'. Do you see any page? Strange, somebody must have needed it before :) Yes, I have ORDER BY in final sql, this is only short example. Thanks for info. WITH (ROWLOCK) is needed because we are facing deadlocks (Page Level locks) during massive load (dozens inserts/updates/selects per each second on the same table). I'm aware of its pros and coins (lock escalation etc).

Comment: Can you remove the two `WITH (NOLOCK)` in the CTE? I think that may be the source of conflict.

Comment: I agree that removing the with (nolock) statements in the select is the way to go.  With sensible indexes in place the select statement should be v. quick - what is the execution plan that you're seeing and do you have an index on table1 on col3, id, col2?

Comment: @ZoffDino Thanks for answer. Yes - if I remove WITH (NOLOCK) it will execute without errors. But I want take advantages of 'no locked' selecting top x rows and also benefit of 'only row locked' update. I accept risk of 'dirty reads', I can't wait until all locks finish during selecting x rows, thats why I need WITH (NOLOCK). And I want give a hint on updating, to make only row locks, because page/table locks cause a deadlock situation. (thats why I use WITH (ROWLOCK))

Comment: @PaulMcLoughlin Yes, I have indexes, mainly 'covering indexes'. Luckily we dont have index deadlocks. Only Page level deadlocks are problem, and thats why I try hints WITH (ROWLOCK). And the WITH (NOLOCK) is for performance reason, we need have dozens selects/updates per second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOLOCK` does not apply to the part of the query that references the table to be modified. In SQL Server update statements U-lock each row briefly while it is being tested. This is a deadlock avoidance mechanism. It prevents multiple updates to each S-lock a row for reading and then try to X-lock it.

You cannot make the U-locks go away AFAIK. But you can reduce the amount of rows U-locked to the abolute minimum by self joining:

```
update t1
set ...
from T t1 with (rowlock)
where t1.ID in (select TOP 5 ID from T t2 with (nolock) where ... order by ...)
```

This adds a little overhead but it allows you to use `NOLOCK` for reading.

Consider using snapshot isolation for the reads. `NOLOCK` has certain problems such as queries randomly aborting.